# git pull in a hook not executing

Tags: git

I have a system setup like this:

http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

However no matter how I configure the shell environment (i.e. GIT_DIR and PWD) the git-pull command does NOT run when called by the hook. Literally there is NO output whatsoever.

My post-update looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh    
/git/Lunch.git/lunch-receive > lunch.txt
```

and my lunch-receive script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
service myService stop
cd /usr/lunch
unset GIT_DIR
git reset --hard # necessary or the pull fails
git pull hub master # this line DOESN'T RUN grrrrr!
chmod u+x *.sh
chmod -R u+x bin
service myService start
```

Finally, lunch.txt (the output) looks like

```
HEAD is now at 5956c0b [old commit message]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absurdly, changing

```
/git/Lunch.git/lunch-receive > lunch.txt
```

to:

```
/git/Lunch.git/lunch-receive > lunch.txt 2>&1
```

and

```
git pull hub master
```

to:

```
 echo before-pull
 git pull --verbose hub master || echo "git-pull: returned error code"
 echo after-pull
```

seemed to have fixed the problem

Comment: Any idea why if I put the line `exec git --git-dir /home/gcom370p/stu013/express/.git pull /home/gcom370p/stu013/express.git master` in the middle of my post-receive hook anything after this line won't execute?